# Why is PyPy3 slower at starting new Processes?

Tags: python, performance, process, multiprocessing, pypy

I would like to know why when I start new Processes (multiprocessing.Process) in PyPy3, it is actually like 2 times slower than doing the same thing on CPython. I would also like to know any solutions for this.

This is some code I wrote for illustrating this effect:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from time import sleep, time

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do other stuff
        #self.p_conn, self.child_conn = mp.Pipe()
        #self.q = mp.Queue()

    def do_something(self, i):
        sleep(0.1)
        s = '%s * %s = %s' % (i, i, i*i)
        #self.child_conn.send(s)
        #self.q.put(i**2)

    def run(self):
        processes = []

        for i in range(500):
            p = mp.Process(target=self.do_something, args=(i,))
            processes.append(p)

        [x.start() for x in processes]

        #for i in range(50):
        #    print(self.p_conn.recv())

        #for i in range(50):
        #    print(self.q.get())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    s = time()
    a.run()
    print(f"Took {time()-s} seconds...")
```

CPython took around 18 seconds while PyPy3 took around 37 seconds to execute the same code. (Other tests also showed that PyPy3 is 2 times slower than CPython at starting Processes in my system...)

I would like to know **how to solve the problem** efficiently.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: You are creating a whole new interpreter process. PyPy is JIT compiled. It is *generally slower* until the JIT has had time to "warm up". And I believe it just has higher start-up costs. This is my suspicion

Comment: If you want such a simple code to be fast you need to get away from using processes. Processes are heavy and creating them is a very expensive task which is Ok only if the computation time is quite big. The Startup of PyPy is slower because PyPy as much more things to initialize than CPython not to mention the warmup time. Consider using **threads** while possibly releasing the GIL (See CPython, Numba or even PyPy experimental transactional memory). If you cannot or do not want to, then you need a bigger computation time. Note that Windows processes are slower to create than Linux/Mac.

Comment: This test is rather silly  for a couple reasons: (1) you're making 500 processes and I doubt your CPU has that many cores -- try `cpu_count()` at most (2) the processes are just sleeping, not real CPU-bound work. Use threads if you want them to babysit something like a network request or subprocess call.